# ASP Email client error, Gridview and checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gridview

I'm having a problem executing the following code, I am creating a email system which I can select multiple emails by clicking a checkbox in a gridview. Once i select the emails i want and hit the send button I receive the following error

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

Here is my code below
Any help is appreciated

```
protected void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //Array list to hold selected email ids
        ArrayList emailArray = new ArrayList();
        //Looping through rows of GridView
        foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            //Creating checkbox object using the find control method
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)item.Cells[1].FindControl("CheckBox1");
            //CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("CheckBox1");
            //Checking whether checkbox is checked or not
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                //If checked Adding email id to Arraylist
                emailArray.Add(GridView1.DataKeys[item.RowIndex]["email"].ToString());
            }
        }
        //Looping through the email id list
        foreach (string email in emailArray)
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress("siscsc3047@gmail.com");
            msg.To.Add(email);

            msg.Subject = subjecttext.Text;
            msg.Body = TextBox1.Text;
            SmtpClient smt = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            smt.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("siscsc3047@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxxx");
            smt.EnableSsl = true;
            smt.Send(msg);
            //}
        }
        emailsent.Text = "Email has been sent Successfully";
    }
}  

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Visible="true"
    CssClass="mydatagrid" EmptyDataText="No Students Enrolled on this Module" 
    EmptyDataRowStyle-BorderWidth="0px" PagerStyle-CssClass="pager" 
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows"   
    DataSourceID="displayemail">  
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="email" SortExpression="name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: have you set a break point and stepped through it? Where exactly is the error being thrown?

Comment: Im quite new to ASP so not sure what a break point is, the point there error is thrown is         emailArray.Add(GridView1.DataKeys[item.RowIndex]["email"].ToString());

Comment: can you post the gridview markup?

Comment: on Visual Studio, click on the left side bar, it will add a break point, then you can run in debug mode and it will stop execution on that line

Comment: Added code but formatting for code section not working right

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is setting `DataKeyName` property of GridView. Your `GridView` should be changed as following.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Visible="true"
    CssClass="mydatagrid" EmptyDataText="No Students Enrolled on this Module" 
    EmptyDataRowStyle-BorderWidth="0px" PagerStyle-CssClass="pager" 
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows"   
    DataSourceID="displayemail" DataKeyNames="email">  
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="email" SortExpression="name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```